# Elixir recovering erl_crash.dump from a k8s pod with memory issues

Tags: elixir

I have Elixir code running on Kubernetes pods which crashes from what I suspect is a memory issue. Once Elixir crashes the pod restarts and doesn't have the erl_crash.dump anywhere under the /opt/ directory, I suspect because the pod is ephemeral.

The log message I get is,

```
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Is there some way to write this file to an s3 bucket or see what it's contents are to get more granular info on why the crash is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

One option I would consider is mounting some node-local storage into the pod and setting `$ERL_CRASH_DUMP` to point to it. You can do that in the `rel/env.sh.eex` file.

Then use a DaemonSet pod to watch the same volume for these files and push them to S3.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a persistent volume to the pods - this way you don't lose the file at reboot and you can retrieve it afterwards.

Comment: And you could maybeuse an initContainer to push it to S3, rather than add that (minor) complexity to your startup script.